# Creating AVI file from BufferedImages in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, avi

I want to ask you what is the simplest way to create avi file from list of Buffered Images?

Comment: But there are some external programs that do this

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2173398/2063026) on a different question. You can use [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR) if you don't want to use external programs but JMF is pretty old so external programs might be a better choice.